# pg-promise thinks my database table doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I am trying to get up and running with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), but it thinks my database table doesn't exist, and I am not sure why.

**app.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const { db } = require("./database.js");
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  db.one("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = $1", 1)
    .then((record) => {
      console.log(record);
      res.send("Success");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.send("Error");
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

**.env**

```
DATABASE_CONNECTION=postgres://adamzerner:<iputmyrealpasswordhere>@localhost:5432/calibration-training
```

**database.js**

```
const pgp = require("pg-promise")();
const db = pgp(process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION);

module.exports = { pgp, db };
```

Then when I hit the endpoint, this is what gets logged:

```
code/calibration-training-api [master●] » yarn start
yarn run v1.22.10
$ node app.js
Example app listening at http://localhost:8080
error: relation "test" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/adamzerner/code/calibration-training-api/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/adamzerner/code/calibration-training-api/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/adamzerner/code/calibration-training-api/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/adamzerner/code/calibration-training-api/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
  length: 103,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '15',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '1384',
  routine: 'parserOpenTable'
}
```

But looking in [Beekeeper Studio](https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/), it shows that the table exists with a record, and the SQL query works there.

[image]

`public.test` doesn't work either, nor does `calibration-training.public.test`, or `Test` or `"Test"` or `"test"`.

`psql` also shows that the table exists:

```
code/calibration-training-api [master●] » psql
psql (14.0)
Type "help" for help.

adamzerner=# \c calibration-training
You are now connected to database "calibration-training" as user "adamzerner".
calibration-training=# \dt
         List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |   Owner
--------+------+-------+------------
 public | Test | table | adamzerner
(1 row)
```

Comment: I didn't implement any AI in `pg-promise`, so it cannot think, sorry (the author).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `test` and `"Test"` are 2 different table names.

Check camel-case + escaping SQL names in PostgreSQL ;)

Comment: Oh wow, I could have sworn I had tried `"Test"`. Thanks for the assist! (I'm new to postgres.)